# Quickest framework to develop a Facebook App - CakePHP vs. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, cakephp

So I know this has been asked before here:
[How to start facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81874/how-to-start-facebook-app)

But I am banking on it being a little old and also hoping I have something slightly more specific to ask. So here goes:

I want to build a basic Facebook app, that would require a basic database, a simple front page, and obviously the ability to share/Like over the feed. Now my main concern is I want to do this quickly and easily, without having to deal with as many mundane details as I can avoid.

I was thus looking at CakePHP and Ruby on Rails as frameworks. However, I am not familiar with *either* of these technologies (I do have a software background, but it is mostly C/C++/Java). So which do you think would be best for me to pick up for this project that will enable me to quickly and easily just 'build' something like this for Facebook?

(Also note that I need a free hosting provider as I don't have money to finance this hobby now, so I'll need to know which hosting companies support these frameworks for free).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the great answers - I forgot to mention, I am open to using any other framework besides what you have mentioned too if you think they are a little but more tailored for Facebook App development and would be a good stepping stone.

Answer (score 10):

Rails, definitely, there are infinitely more and better resources available to learn from and you can get fantastic free hosting (for small scale apps, plus easily scale for cheap) on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com).

To get started, see:

- [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) (free)
- [Rails 3 Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)
- [Railscasts](http://www.railscasts.com)

I was in the same situation as you last fall, I knew a fair amount of PHP but had never worked with an MVC web framework before. I tried to learn CakePHP, struggled for a while, then thought I'd spend just one weekend giving Rails a chance. I had never touched Ruby before, but I was so curious about Rails that I picked up a copy of [Beginning Rails 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224339), and I figured I would just take one weekend and see how hard it was to learn some basic Ruby and get an idea for how Rails works.

I thought going into that weekend that there was really no way learning a whole new language could be worth it, even if the framework suited me better. I'm so, so glad I gave it a chance. Ruby is awesome, the community behind it is phenomenal, and the amount of documentation, screencasts, tutorials, etc. are out of this world. Ruby is also a lot of fun to work with, and very easy to learn. [Try for yourself](http://TryRuby.org/) and see what you think.

Rails is definitely the way to go (vs CakePHP at least).

Comment: Interesting - yes some of the research I have done does seem to suggest Ruby is much 'cleaner' and 'tighter' which I like. I'll look into ti further - thanks for the resources!

Answer (score 4):

The answers so far only scratch the surface!

CakePHP is to PHP what Rails is to Ruby. From the onset, CakePHP was developed to mimic the "Rails" way on things, and has done really well so far; but if you're starting from scratch; you need to remember you have to:

- Set up a development environment, which in turn involves

  - Install the language (PHP / Ruby) and Database (MySQL?)
  - Learning some basic server configuration(s)
  - Choosing which one is right for you, and setting it up (Apache, Nginx, Passenger etc)
  - Get the framework up and running
- Learn the underlying language
- Learn the framework
- Learn the Facebook API, and their developer guidelines
- Actually Build the application
- Test it, debug and submit for approval
- Launch it

Having developed in both CakePHP and RoR - if you're coming with no web development background and you're looking to start; dive in with either. Honestly, it'll be the same learning curve for you! You will find the setup, learning, development and deployment easier in CakePHP - PHP is one of the most popular languages. If you want to learn a language and framework also to improve your skills as a programmer and developer, then you want RoR - it's got strict conventions that do twist your mind but once you get the hang of it, there's no looking back (and these are the same conventions that CakePHP is trying to bring to the PHP world!).

The official documentation for both is excellent, they have amazing (and very active!) communities where even the silliest question is answered. There are also excellent (free) hosting platforms available, that make use of Git and make deployment a snap ([PHPFog](https://www.phpfog.com/) and [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)).

It might be worth mentioning that RoR is considered the new boy on the scene, the trendy framework thats bringing with it a lot of rapid changes in development methodologies, and that RoR developers also are in very high demand.

Also - considering the simplicity of the App - have you considered using [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) (a very minimal framework for Ruby)? You may find that the easiest, and it'll be an excellent stepping stone if you later wanted to get into Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this thread is about 1 1/2 years old by the time I write this. But wanted to add something to the discussion for anyone finding this, as I did doing a search on RoR vs CakePHP.

As of this date, and during the last 12 months, RoR is trending about 3 times what CakePHP is, according to [Google Trends](http://goo.gl/Gs46m). Now, this is just RoR vs CakePHP.

When I add Facebook into the mix, RoR/Facebook is still about 3 times CakePHP/Facebook, but if you look at the last 3 months, CakePHP/Facebook drops to zero. [Link](http://goo.gl/9rdKV).

Right now, the trending languages for Facebook apps are C, Java, & C++. [Link](http://goo.gl/FIPRJ).

Answer (score 2):

If you are more familiar with C/C++ then you will most likely find the learning curve for PHP a lot less steep : )

For something like a Facebook app and already knowing C, I would look into CakePHP. If you have time in the future look into RoR as it is an amazing platform.

Comment: Yea, that is my main confusion - PHP seems like it's a lot more ubiquitous, where as Ruby just seems like something of a revolution, so I can't seem to figure out what to get started with first.

Comment: Don't worry cakephp is similar to rails and rails uses ruby so learning them in that order is smart php->cakephp->rails->ruby

Comment: i didn't do much with Rails (and its various forms) but citizen conn is right. the learning curve from php -> cakephp is amazing. so is the curve from cakephp -> Rails

Answer (score 2):

Don't get me wrong, I love CakePHP. But if you don't have a background in web programming (PHP in particular), even CakePHP can take quite some time to be familiar with. RoR would be at the same learning curve, I suppose.

Besides, to deal with facebook API, you'll have to interact with it at 'base' level (by which I mean, the framework can't help you much with it). So to "quickly and easily just 'build' something like this for Facebook?" I don't think it's quite possible.

Anyway, if you still want to do it, CakePHP would be easier for you because PHP syntax would be similar to C and Java. But Ruby is an interesting and unique language if you have the time to spend on it.

Comment: Cool - what do you think the learning curve would be? I mean, what was your learning experience? I'd like to know what expectations I should set for myself.

Comment: @Pratik -- for what it's worth, using the Beginning Rails 3 book I went from no ruby or rails experience to a good understanding of the framework and the core of my app finished in one week.